# Processing Custom Cursor Issue

Tags: processing

I'm currently using Processing 3.0.1 on MacOSX, and am having trouble with setting a custom image for the cursor. Specifically, the cursor flickers between my custom image and the default image.

The documentation says there are issues when running fullscreen, but the problem persists in a window as well.

Relevant code:

```
PImage cursorGreen;
void setup(){
  cursorGreen = loadImage("img/cursor.png");
  cursorGreen.resize(16,16);
}
void draw(){
  cursor(cursorGreen);
}
```

---

EDIT: Restarted my computer and it seems to be working fine. Maybe a memory problem or something...

Comment: Processing 3.0.1 came out only a few days ago, so it may be a bug. I'm going to update now to see if I get the same problem.

Comment: Nope, I tried your code on Mac OS X Yosemite with a JPG and a PNG, and there wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me on Windows 10 using Processing 3.0.

One thing that jumps out to me is: why are you constantly setting the cursor in the draw function, which is called 60 times per second? Try just setting it once instead:

```
void setup(){
  PImage cursorGreen = loadImage("img/cursor.png");
  cursorGreen.resize(16,16);
  cursor(cursorGreen);
}
void draw(){
  //whatever
}
```

Comment: Resolved the problem by restarting my machine, but this is a good point.